# I need a VBA script to run on excel to copy all my access tables columns in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have about 10 *.mdb Access files of office version 2003. I am working on client machines on which I have only Excel 2003 installed but not Access.

Each database file has around 50-100 tables in it and each tables has around 20-30 columns. I need to run a VBA script or any import on Excel so that I could copy all the Access tables and its columns into my Excel sheet. I do not require data of Access tables only the table and its column names is what I require.

Comment: can u suggest some sites where to look for it.. I am completely new to all this..

Comment: Type ado schemas into google and see how you get on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plan:

```
For Each MDB In YourMdbs (file in folder, hard-coded list, ...)
    For Each TABLE In MDB (filtered, no MSys tables, ...)
        XLS = FSpec to non-existing .xls corresponding to MDB
        Execute on ADO connection to XLS:
          SELECT * INTO <TABLE> FROM <TABLE> IN "<FSpec to MDB>" WHERE 1=0
```

based on: [IN CLAUSE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080761082.aspx)

This approach will export the .mdbs table schemata to .xls sheets **without** any fuss with ADOX schema.

**WRT comments:**

1. The program from VBS Express **documents** the table and the field names, my strategy **copies** the tables (without data because of the WHERE clause) to the sheets
2. ADO magic works on computers without MS Office installed just fine

Comment: Thanks.. I used the approach mentioned here..
http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=707

I looped in the directory to find mdb files and then use above procedure to find tables and column. It was easy one..

Comment: I used DAO.OpenDatabase to open the access database in my excel module.. so this solved the issue of me not having ms access installed..